# What kind of a valve is this?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, washing-machine, valve

I need to turn off the water supply to this washing machine.

What kind of a valve is this? How do I operate it?

Furthermore, why are there three rubber wires that leave the hot and cold water pipes?

Thanks

EDIT:

Maybe these two steel nobs are opening/closing the valves? You see them? It's those two steel colored thingies, one on the right, one on the left.

Furthermore, what are those cylinders for? What the hell is that? I've never seen that before.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hot and cold to the washer, maybe a line from the cold for steam to the dryer? It’s hard to tell from your photos, but I suspect the valve is above where those hoses come out, maybe quarter turn valves?

Comment: I don’t see a shutoff. Perhaps more pictures like the first. Three water lines are likely cold, hot, and one for a steam feature on your dryer

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean I added an interesting picture. Can you kindly take a look at it? There are like two steel nobs, one on each pipe.

Comment: @kponz I don't see a quarter valve there but I added a new picture where you can see a kind of nob one each line. Maybe that closes and opens the water? What do you think.

Comment: google `water hammer arrestor` ... look at pictures and read descriptions

Comment: There are no valves there. All those "knobs" are hose connectors.

Comment: The original photos were photos of the screen of a special camera.  Very weak in red, so super cyan. Fixed in photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

Those two knobs, the tiny ones on the inner sides of the hose connectors are the valves.

[image]

Comment: I’d love to see a picture of it removed cause I still don’t recognize a valve even with the arrows

Answer (score 1):

The cylinders are to reduce water hammer (they are basically shock adsorbers for the water that's moving in the pipe being suddenly stopped by the very fast valves inside the washing machine.)